# No keyboard in Chat

Tags: bug, chat, ios-app

When accessing chat from within the Stack Exchange app, no keyboard is brought up when trying to add a message or edit an existing one.   I had to access the chat via a web browser external to the app in order to get  access to a keyboard in order to reply.  I exited the app numerous times and even got rid of my third-party keyboard to make sure it wasn't just that. Nothing worked to fix it.

[Here](https://youtu.be/TOzBWhbOrms) is a quick demo.

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPhone 7 Plus
- OS Version: Version 11.4.1 (Build 15G77)

Comment: Are you sure you actually *joined* the chatroom (as opposed to viewing the transcript, which happens e.g. when you open a chat notification)? FWIW, I just tested it but I can't reproduce it.

Comment: Yes.  I'm sure I joined. I'll take a recording of what happens and link it here. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: @Glorfindel Here is a quick demo of it in action. https://youtu.be/TOzBWhbOrms

Comment: Great, thanks for posting the video.

Comment: @Glorfindel Sure. So, after seeing it in action, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I don't think so, so you get a +1 from me for posting a bug report with evidence :)

Comment: @Glorfindel LOL. Nice. Thanks.